# Is there an HLSL plugin available for Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, hlsl

Something that at least would add code syntax coloring?

HLSL 3 preferably.

Answer (score 1):

The InteliShade website appears to be dead in the water, unfortunately.  While I have not yet found another plugin to add hlsl highlighting, I did find some [manual instructions](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/viewreply.asp?ID=2924456) on gamedev.net to add the syntax highlighting definitions to Visual Studio.

> You have to download the [CG Toolkit](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/cg_toolkit.html)
>   from the nVidia site. Then in the
>   folder \NVIDIA
>   Corporation\Cg\msdev_syntax_highlighting\
>   its gonna be a file called
>   usertype.dat then you will have to do
>   this..
>
> 1. Copy the usertype.dat file to \Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE
> 2. Open up the registry editor and go to the following location -
>      HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\Languages\File
>      Extensions
> 3. Copy the default value from the .cpp key.
> 4. Create a new key under the File Extensions with the name of .cg
> 5. Paste the value you just copied into the default value.
> 6. Restart Visual Studio and your shaders should now have syntax
>      highlighting.
>
> and it will be all set.

Comment: I think those directions actually come from the readme file provided in the CG Toolkit. @skaffman NShader is a nice plugin that provides highlighting for VS 2008/2010, I realize you're looking for something for 2005 though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is. It is called InteliShade and can be found at http://intelishade.net/

Answer (score 0):

Intelishade Seems to work well, Used it while working with the XNA framework, Still suck at coding shaders tho >.>